# How to set end of string in Python regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-re

I have the following list

```
lst = ['BILL_FROM:', 'MyCompany', '525._S._Lexington_Ave.', 'Burlington._NC._2725', 'United_States', 'musicjohnliofficial@gmail.com', 'BILL_TO:', 'O.Relly', '343._S._Lexington_Ave.', 'Burlington._NC._2725', 'United_States', 'musicjohnliofficial@gmail.com', 'INVOICE_number', '01', 'INVOICE_DATE', '2022-12-27', 'AMOUNT_DUE', '1.128', 'SUBTOTAL', '999.00', 'TAX_(13.0%)', '129.87', 'TOTAL', '1.128']
```

And I want to get it's `BILL_TO:` field using regex.

I'm trying to do

```
>>> bill_to = re.compile("(\w+)to$", re.IGNORECASE)
>>> list(filter(bill_to.match, lst))
```

to get `['BILL_TO:']` field only, but instead getting

```
['Burlington._NC._2725', 'BILL_TO:', 'Burlington._NC._2725', 'SUBTOTAL']
```

Why the `$` symbol is not working here? Or am I doing something else wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect from the given input list, and provide an explanation in case the logic might not be clear.

Comment: you missed the `:` -- try `"(\w+)to:$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` will match the end of the string, but you have a `:` beforehand which you also need to match:

```
(\w+)to:$
```

Also, it's recommended to use a raw string to escape the `\` (notice the `r`):

```py
bill_to = re.compile(r"(\w+)to:$", re.IGNORECASE)
```